# Changing background image of soft keyboard popup keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, popup

How can I change the background image of the popup keyboard (the small keyboard that appears when the user long-touches a key)?

Answer (score 0):

you need to extend an `InputMethodService`

and then build your UI in:

```
@Override 
public View onCreateInputView()
```

see:

- http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2009/04/creating-input-method.html
- http://gitorious.org/0xdroid/packages_inputmethods_latinime/blobs/ab17fca519fa27af01d29a38c553e250c9e92a9e/src/com/android/inputmethod/latin/LatinIME.java

Comment: Thanks very much, but I was hoping to be able to do it in XML. After all, I can change the background image of the regular keys and the preview box in XML.